# Boto is unable to access bucket inside ECS container which have correct IAM roles (but Boto3 can)

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, boto3, amazon-iam

I have ECS container and I have attached an IAM policy like below:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:Get*"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my_s3_bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

and have both boto and boto3 installed in it.

I am able to list bucket using boto3 but not by boto. Please see code below:

```
import boto3
s3_conn = boto3.client('s3')
s3_conn.list_objects(Bucket='my_s3_bucket')

'Owner': {u'DisplayName': 'shoppymcgee', u'ID': 'adf3425700e4f995d8773a8b********'}, u'Size': 116399950}, {u'LastModified': datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 18, 6, 35, 6, tzinfo=tzlocal()), u'ETag': '"2b4a4d60458cde1685c93dabf98c6e19"', u'StorageClass': 'STANDARD', u'Key': u'2013/05/18/SLPH_201305180605_eligible-product-feed.txt', u'Owner': {u'DisplayName': 'shoppymcgee', u'ID': 'adf3425700e4f995d8773a8be6b0df09d06751f3274d8be5e8ae04761a5eef09'},

import boto
conn = boto.connect_s3()
print conn
S3Connection:s3.amazonaws.com
mybucket = conn.get_bucket('my_s3_bucket')


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 509, in get_bucket
    return self.head_bucket(bucket_name, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 528, in head_bucket
    response = self.make_request('HEAD', bucket_name, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 671, in make_request
    retry_handler=retry_handler
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1071, in make_request
    retry_handler=retry_handler)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 943, in _mexe
    request.body, request.headers)
```

Version of boto - boto==2.48.0

Version of boto3 and botocore - botocore==1.7.41 and boto3==1.4.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boto does not support the `AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI` environment variable, which is what gives containers/tasks the ability to use the task-specific IAM role.

If you do a search on GitHub for that environment variable in Boto's repository, you'll come up with no code hits and an open issue asking for it to be implemented - https://github.com/boto/boto/search?q=AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI

Until support is added (if it will be at all given boto's maintenance state), the only way to use boto is to [call the metadata service manually](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html) on `curl 169.254.170.2$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI`, retrieve the credentials and manually pass them to boto (be careful of the expiry on the temporary credentials though).

Or migrate to boto3.